# seg fault at memory that is already there

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So I just started using valgrind and having a hard time figuring out what all the different errors are and what number means. 
for example I am getting a seg fault at this line. ( I know this not because valgrind shown me but me just putting each line by line back into my and check it until it seg faults when running my program * which in function2 in my code)

```
 int what = t->count;
```

Its trying to pull memory from my int count in my struct orderlist, and I know that I inputed it beforehand. I don't know why I cant pull it out.
can some tell me what valgrind is trying to tell me?

I have tried making sure the program doesnt seg fault anywhere else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "orderList_ccarver4_211.c"

void selectChoice();
void function1();
void function2();

typedef struct _robotOrder
{
    unsigned char robotNum;
    orderList *data;
    char *deliverTo;
    char *restaurant;
    struct _robotOrder *next;
} robotOrder;

robotOrder *deliveryList; /* the head of linked list of robotOrders */
robotOrder *addfront(robotOrder *head, robotOrder *value);

int main(void){
    deliveryList = (robotOrder*)dmalloc(sizeof(robotOrder)); /* the head of linked list of robotOrders */

    selectChoice(); /* choice menu function*/

    return 0;
}

void selectChoice()
{
    int T = 1;
    char line[4];
    char c;
    do{
        printf(" New delivery order? (y/n) "); /* get users choice*/
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        c = line[0];

        printf("yo this is it = %c\n", c);

        switch (c)
        {
        case 'y':
            function1();
            break;
        case 'n':
            printf("here");
            function2();
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid Input. Try again\n");

        }
    } while(T > 0);
}

robotOrder* addfront(robotOrder *head, robotOrder *value) /* function that adds to the list in the front */
{
    robotOrder *p,*q;
    p = (robotOrder*)dmalloc(sizeof(robotOrder));
    q = (robotOrder*)dmalloc(sizeof(robotOrder));
    p = head;
    q = value;
    q->next= p;
    return (q);
}

void function1(){

    robotOrder *or = (robotOrder*)dmalloc(sizeof(robotOrder)); /* makes a new robot order */

    char string[5];
    int num;
    printf("Task Robot Number: "); /* gets the num of the robot*/
    fgets(string, 4, stdin);
    num = atoi(string);
    or->robotNum = num;

    char *line;
    line=(char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
    printf("Delivery Address for new delivery order: "); /* gets the address*/
    fgets(line,sizeof(line), stdin);
    sscanf(line,"%s",&line);
    or->deliverTo = line;


    char *lines;
    lines=(char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
    printf("Restaurant from which to pick up food: "); /* gets the name of the restaurant*/
    fgets(lines,sizeof(lines), stdin);
    sscanf(lines,"%s",&lines);
    or->restaurant = lines;

    int loop = 0;
    char l[20];
    createItem();
    orderList *p = (orderList*)dmalloc(sizeof(orderList));
    int s = 0;
    while(loop == 0){
        printf("food item: "); /* keeps asking for food items*/
        fgets(l,sizeof(l), stdin);
        sscanf(l,"%s",&l);
        if(l[0] == '\n'){
            loop = 1; /* ends the loop if there wasnt any input */
        }
        if(l[0] != '\n'){
            s = s + insert(l, p); /* takes in the orderlist that in the robotorder */
        }
    }
    p->count = s;
    or->data = p; /* sets the orderlist to the robotOrder */

    deliveryList = addfront(deliveryList, or); /* add the node to the end of the list */

}

void function2(){
    printf("hello ?");
    robotOrder *p = (robotOrder*)dmalloc(sizeof(robotOrder));
    p = deliveryList;
    orderList *t = (orderList*)dmalloc(sizeof(orderList));
    while(p != NULL){ /* prints out info of the deliveries */
        t = p->data;
        int what = t->count;
        printf("Robot %d: Delivery order from %s has %d food item(s)", p->robotNum, p->restaurant,what);
        p = p->next;

        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("goodbye");
    exit(0); /* exit program */
}
```

orderList c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "orderList_ccarver4_211.h"

orderList *createItem(){
    orderList *lis = (orderList*)dmalloc(sizeof(orderList));
    lis->count = 0;
    lis->head = NULL;
}

int insert(char *str, orderList *s){
    foodNode *h;
    h = (foodNode*)dmalloc(sizeof(foodNode));
    h = s->head;
    int len = s->count;


    foodNode *q;
    q = (foodNode*)dmalloc(sizeof(foodNode)); /* makes new node */
    q->data = str;

    if(s->head == NULL){
        h=q;
        s->head = q;
        len++;
        s->count = len;
        return 1;
    }
    char *str2 = h->data; /* grabs the data*/
    int com = strcmpi(str, str2);
    while(h != NULL) {
        if(h->next == NULL){
            h->next = q;
            len++;
            s->count = len;
            return 1;
        }
        h = h->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

void printItems(orderList *s){
    foodNode *p;
    p = (foodNode*)dmalloc(sizeof(foodNode));
    p = s->head;
    while(p != NULL){
        printf("%s", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

/* compares strings for alphabetical ordering */
int strcmpi(char *s, char *t)
{
    while (*s && tolower(*s) == tolower(*t))
    {
        s++;
        t++;
    }
    return tolower(*s) - tolower(*t);
}

/* allocates memory with a check for successful allocation */
void *dmalloc(size_t size)
{
    void *p = malloc(size);
    if (!p)
    {
        printf("memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return p;
}
```

orderList h file

```
#ifndef ORDERLIST_CCARVER4_211_H
#define ORDERLIST_CCARVER4_211_H

typedef struct _foodNode
{
   char *data;  // Food Item Names
   struct _foodNode *next;
} foodNode;

typedef struct _orderList
{
   foodNode *head;  // Pointer to first food item for the order (alphabetical)
   int count;   // Number of food items in the order
} orderList;

orderList *createItem();
int insert(char *str, orderList *s);
void printItems(orderList *s);
int strcmpi(char *s, char *t);
void *dmalloc(size_t size);

#endif
```

This is what valgrind gave me, What does read of size 1 mean and where should I be looking?

> ==1612== Invalid read of size 1
>   ==1612==    at 0x4E81EF9: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1635)
>   ==1612==    by 0x4E88328: printf (printf.c:34)
>   ==1612==    by 0x400D5E: function2 (Project3_ccarver4_211.c:127)
>   ==1612==    by 0x400A9C: selectChoice (Project3_ccarver4_211.c:50)
>   ==1612==    by 0x400A10: main (Project3_ccarver4_211.c:26)
>   ==1612==  Address 0x61646e6170 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
>   ==1612==
>   ==1612==
>   ==1612== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
>   ==1612==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x61646E6170
>   ==1612==    at 0x4E81EF9: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1635)
>   ==1612==    by 0x4E88328: printf (printf.c:34)
>   ==1612==    by 0x400D5E: function2 (Project3_ccarver4_211.c:127)
>   ==1612==    by 0x400A9C: selectChoice (Project3_ccarver4_211.c:50)
>   ==1612==    by 0x400A10: main (Project3_ccarver4_211.c:26)
>   ==1612==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
>   ==1612==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
>   ==1612==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
>   ==1612==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
>   ==1612==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
>   herehello ?Robot 27: Delivery order from ==1612==

Comment: Lots of problems here.  You are calling `dmalloc`, then immediately discarding the result.  This is done in many places.  E.g. `p = dmalloc(...);` followed immediately by `p = (something else);`  So the first value of `p` is permanently lost (memory leak), and the `dmalloc` call serves no purpose.

Comment: How do I store the a value to something else without memory leaking?

Comment: should I just get rid of the dmalloc?

Comment: Only if you immediately assign a different value to the variable, like in `addfront`.

Comment: The error indicates that you're using an uninitialized value of `foodNode.data`, or maybe you've dereferenced an incorrect pointer and overwrite that `data`.

Comment: Why are you calling `dmalloc` in the first place?  If you need dynamically allocated memory, then you need to save the result of `dmalloc` and actually *use* it someplace (which you aren't).  If you don't, then sure, remove them all.

Comment: NEVER `#include` a *.c file.  Rather, compile it separately into an object file.  then use the `link` step to combine all the object files into an executable.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Comment: regarding: `sscanf(l,"%s",&l);`  the array `l` (terrible name for an array) when referenced ,alone, results in `char*` of the address of the first byte of the array.  However, `&l`  results in a type: `char (*)[20]` which is not correct

Comment: regarding the function signature: `orderList *createItem()`  this indicates that the function returns a pointer to a 'orderList' however, the body of the function returns nothing. And where it is called does not expect a returned value,  Suggest changing the signature to: `void createitem()`

Comment: regarding: `orderList *createItem();` in the header file;   this says that the parameter list can be anything.  That is not what you want,  Suggest: `orderList *createItem( void );`

Comment: Note: since the function: `createItem()` does not return the created item AND the caller to this function does not check for a returned value, either the logic is wrong or this function can be removed

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `printf("memory allocation failed\n");`  1) Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.   2) when an error indication is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the function failed.  The function: `perror()` outputs both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: this statement: `exit(1);` in function: `dmalloc()` will result in a unrecoverable memory leak.  Before calling `exit()`, the code needs to pass all the pointers to allocated memory to `free()`

Comment: in function: `strcmpi()`, this statement: ` while (*s && tolower(*s) == tolower(*t))` has the logic error of (possibly) comparing past the end of the char array pointed to by `t`

Comment: regarding: `p = (foodNode*)dmalloc(sizeof(foodNode));`  The returned type from `dmalloc()` is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc  Suggest removing the cast

Comment: OT: function names should indicate what they do, preferably with an action verb, like `get/set/calc/etc`  function names like: `function2()` are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: OT: regarding this kind of statement: `typedef struct _foodNode`  in C, names starting with an underscore are 'reserved' for the environment.  Strongly suggest removing all those leading underscores